# Do not Enforce Foreign Key Constraints in fluent nhibernate / nhibernate

Tags: sql-server-2008, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I am wondering how do you setup in fluent nhibernate to tell that a relationship should NOT "Enforce Foreign Key Constraints"

http://gyazo.com/6a1cf3014b0650eb3ff5e05f855abf69

Do you just set the reference to Nullable?

Comment: And what is the point of an Fk that you don't enforce?

Comment: nullable foreign keys are still enforced.  only if the value is null is it "not" enforced.

Comment: The point is you can establish relationships but have more control over the data.  Most frameworks examine foreign keys, but there are lots of times I want to move things around in a way that would not necessarily be expected.  Non-enforced FK's allow me to do that while still letting the ORM know there's an object relationship to consider.

Answer (score 1):

In FluentNHibernate, 'NotFound.Ignore()' might do what you need, eg:

```
References(x => x.Parent).NotFound.Ignore();
```